# How do I know if a QuickBlox message has been throttled

Tags: quickblox

Is there any way of knowing in an QuickBlox app if a message has been throttled due to sending too many messages per second.

I set up a test and sent enough messages to cause throttling, but I can not find any error function or callback that gets called when this happens - it seems the messages are just silently discarded. If this is the case, then it makes me very wary of using QuickBlox.

Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send as many messages as you can and need

In case of throttling you will be disconnected from Chat, but it's a big limit to reach it

Comment: Thanks, it seems strange that QuickBlox plans have a set messages/second and users/month but apparently then provides no way to see what the current or historical usages are. It appears that my app will just fail to send messages or allow users to connect with no way of me knowing this is happening. Up until my users start complaining.